# SSH tunnel not working - empty server response

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to setup an SSH tunnel but I am new to this process. This is my setup:

Machine B has a web service with restricted access. Machine A has been granted access to Machine B's service, based on a firewall IP whitelist.

I can connect to Machine A using an ssh connection. After that I try to access the webservice on Machine B from my localhost, but I cannot.

The webservice endpoint looks like this: 
`service.test.organization.com:443/org/v1/sendData`

So far, I have created an ssh tunnel like this: 
`ssh -L 1234:service.test.organization.com:443 myuser@machineb.com`

My understanding was that using this approach, I could hit localhost:1234 and it would be forwarded to service.test.organization.com:443, through Machine B.

I have confirmed that from Machine B, I can execute a curl command to send a message to the webservice, and i get a response (so that is working). I have tried using PostMan in my browser, and curl in terminal from localhost, but I have been unsuccessful. (`curl -X POST -d @test.xml localhost:1234/org/v1/sendData`)

Error message: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

There's a lot of material on SSH and I am sifting through it, but if anyone has any pointers, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: have you checked that port forwarding is enabled in sshd_config? by default it isnt usually

Comment: I found that the request is making it to the destination but no response is coming back because the request originated from Localhost, which violates the firewall whitelist rule. How can I make it so the HTTP request header says its from Machine B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The networking issue was caused by the request format. My request object was built with a destination of 'localhost:1234'. So even though it was reaching the proper machine, the machine ignored it.

To solve this I added a record in my host file, like this:
`service.test.organization.com    127.0.0.1`

Then I was able send the message. First I opened the tunnel,
`ssh -L 443:service.test.organization.com:443 myuser@machineb.com`,
Then using using this curl command: `curl -X POST -d @test.xml service.test.organization.com:443/org/v1/sendData`

The host file causes the address to resolve to localhost, then the ssh tunnel knows to forward it on.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `Host` HTTP header: `curl -H "Host: service.test.organization.com" -X POST -d @test.xml http://localhost:1234/org/v1/sendData`